# How can I generate a word cloud from tokenized words in Python?

Tags: python, text-mining, word-cloud

I have a code to import a txt file and get tokenized words using NLTK library (just like it is done in https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/text-analytics-beginners-nltk). I did almost everything I needed easily, however I'm struggling to build a word cloud with the words I have now and I don't have any clue even after hours of search on the web.

This is my code so far:

```
# Carrega bibliotecas
!pip install nltk
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

# Import file
f = open('PNAD2002.txt','r')
pnad2002 = ""
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:break
    pnad2002 += line

f.close()

tokenized_word=word_tokenize(pnad2002)

tokenized_word_2 = [w.lower() for w in tokenized_word]
```

I wanted to use the following code (from https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.py):

```
# Read the whole text.
text = open(path.join(d, 'constitution.txt')).read()

# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")

# lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=40).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

But I don't know how to use my tokenized words with this.

Comment: There's a really useful [wordcloud package](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud)

Comment: @G.Anderson I found this example before and I tried to use it, however I can't make it work. For instance, if I use 'tokenized_word_2' as text, the code provided doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instanciate a `WordCloud` object then call `generate_from_text`:

```py
wc = WordCloud()
img = wc.generate_from_text(' '.join(tokenized_word_2))
img.to_file('worcloud.jpeg') # example of something you can do with the img
```

There's a bunch of customization you can pass to `WordCloud`, you can find examples online such as this: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python

Comment: Thanks @aiguofer, that works fine! But I still have one more question... can I do something similar with tokenized words (from NLKT)? Because with this I can use the words already filtered (without stopwords)

Comment: yep! also, I edited it since `generate_from_text` expects a string, if you have all your words in a list as is the case in `tokenized_word` then you can turn that into text easily using `' '.join(tokenized_word)`

Comment: There's also a `stopword` parameter in `WordCloud` so you could pass that in and the library will remove the stopwords for you. It also has parameters to only show words that occurr at least n times. If you type in `WordCloud?` in IPython/Jupyter, you can see the documentation of all the available params.